# Using a count of SSRS 2012 Parameters within the TSQL of my dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Not sure how to do this so was hoping that someone could help, I have a multivalue parameter we shall call '**Week**', this has a drop down of 1 through to 4.  My data set example is :-

select total from tableA where Week in (**@Week**)

what I want to do is divide the total by the number of options I pick from the drop down, e.g. if I picked Week 1 & 2, I would want the TSQL statement to use the count of 2 as the value to divide by e.g.

select total/2 from tableA where Week in (**@Week**)

is this possible?

Thanks P

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into using the Average function,

```
SELECT AVG(total) FROM tableA WHERE Week IN(@Week)
```

Comment: Hi Cube,  Thanks for the response, I did think about using AVG but for some reason if I take the underlying values and paste them in to Excel and work out the Average there compared with using the TSQL I get slightly different though we are looking at figures up to 10 million per week the difference between doing it between TSQL and Excel is never more than about 450 give or take??

Answer (score 1):

I would use a user-defined split function to convert the multivalue parameter into rows in a table. These have been posted several times. Then you can simply do something like this:

```
select sum(A.total), count(distinct Weeks.items)
from tableA as A
inner join dbo.Split(@week) as Weeks on Weeks.items = A.Weeks
```